# Count number of rows in column A that have a value in a list in column B on worksheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of 3 digit phone codes in EST timezone in column A Sheet 2. I have in Column A Sheet 1 another list of 3 digit phone codes from people that have called in.

What I am trying to do is in Sheet 1 "B2" count the number of inbound calls (Column A Sheet 1) that exist in the EST timezone list (Column A Sheet 2).

I cannot seem to find a way to complete this using either formulas or macros.

Comment: You can use `COUNTIF()` for this

Comment: @TimWilliams this does not work when using two ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,'Sheet2'!A##)
```

Just replace `A##` with the location of the 3 digit code from sheet 2 that you want to count.

EDIT:
Here is the code which solves your question. It counts the number of times any value within Sheet2!A:A is iterated in Sheet1!A:A

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A))
```

Comment: This does not accomplish what I am looking to do. I want to take A:A range on sheet 1 and count the number of rows that have values existing in A:A range on sheet 2

Comment: can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish then? I.e. provide an example?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Sure, (Sheet 2 A:A) is my dictionary. It includes all the possible postal codes in the eastern timezone for North America. On (Sheet 1 A:A) I have a list of numbers from people who have called me that may or may not be in the eastern timezone. I want to count the number of times someone has called me from the eastern timezone.

Comment: so wouldn't the countif work for that situation?  On sheet 2, let's say you have a zip code in 'Sheet2'A1, in A2, you can put `=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A:A, $A$2)`

Comment: @JDS Ahh, so you're trying to count all the zip codes in Sheet 2, A:A? So ex:  


    Sheet 1 A:A contains: 303, 650, 650, 313

    and sheet 2, A:2:650, 303

the formula result would be 3?

Comment: YES! sorry I didn't articulate that well enough. Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to solve it for way too long now.

Comment: Try this: `=SUM(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A))`  Be sure to make it an array formula (Control + Shift + Enter).  An array formula will have brackets around it, I.e. `{=SUM(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1:A3))}` after you use ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: At first it didn't work because it was processing over the 200,000+records for a long time. I left it for a bit and it worked. Thank you for your help. I put this into a macro using Selection.FormulaArray = SUM(COUNTIF etc. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. You can always shorten the array within the countif to help minimize the time. Also since you're using a macro, you can turn off screen updating and all that if you haven't already to help speed things up.